# How do I enable a REST resource for a custom content type?

Tags: nodes, 8

I've created a bunch of custom content types like "Car Makes" and "Car Models", but I can't seem to figure out how to enable a REST resource for them. In my REST settings page, I see the default content, content type, user, user registration enabled and a lot of disabled types below it. This list doesn't contain any of my custom created types.

If I go to the permissions page, under "RESTful Web Services", I only see "Administer REST resource configuration" and "Access POST on User registration resource". How can I enable "Car Makes" as a REST resource and directly `GET`/`POST` with it?

I saw this screenshot, but I don't get anything like this in Drupal 8.4:

[image]

In this screenshot, Todo is a custom resource, which requires writing a plugin. Do I have to write a plugin module just to expose each of my custom content types in REST?

I can work directly with the content endpoints, i.e. `POST /node/123`, but I would like to `POST /carmakes`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access these types of content separately, you must do the following:

1. download the module restui: https://www.drupal.org/project/restui/releases/8.x-1.x-dev
2. Go to Extend, activate the modules, HAL, HTTP Basic Authentication, RESTful Web Services, Serialization, and REST UI.
3. go to `/ admin / config / services / rest`
4. Edit the RESOURCE NAME Content, and mark all the checkboxes.
5. Then you should perform a test in the browser with the following path: `drupal8 / node / 1? _format = json`

note: if the information is displayed, it means that the rest server is set correctly.

6. Create a view and select the type of content you want to display and in the "REST EXPORT SETTINGS" section mark the "Provide a REST export" checkbox and in "REST export path" type "car_makes".

This way if you go to the route: `/ drupal8 / en / car_makes` you will see that it will show the information in json format.

Comment: I have already done this. It is only for viewing the resource. I would also like to `POST`, `PATCH` and `DELETE` this resource.

Comment: You can use the gerenal view "/ drupal8 / car_makes" to display the content related to this type of content.

To do the "post, get, path, delete" you must use the path: "drupal8 / node / 1? _format = json"

I made a video in Spanish, in which I do the "post, get, path delete".
The video has a subtitle in English.    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fPNL1r2wEWk&list=PLtg6DxcGyHSvMUUdfGN1st1yOFV1UJGnG

Comment: That's the same as the answer above.